# refreshControl sent two requests when doing pull refresh in FlatList, which should only send once

Tags: react-native

Pull Refresh in FlatList send two requests at the same time, which should only send once

below is the package.json :

```
{
  "name": "githubHelper",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.60.4",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-scrollable-tab-view": "^0.10.0",
    "react-native-tab-navigator": "^0.3.4",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-navigation": "^3.11.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.5.5",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.5.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "0.0.5",
    "babel-jest": "24.8.0",
    "eslint": "6.1.0",
    "jest": "24.8.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.55.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

below is the related code :

```js
    render() {
        return(
           <FlatList
            ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
            keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
            data={this.state.data}
            renderItem={this.renderItem}
            onEndReached={this.handleLoadMore}
            onEndReachedThreshold={0.1}
            ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooterHandler}
            onRefresh={this.refreshingHandler}
            refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
            refreshControl = {
                <RefreshControl
                    refreshing={this.state.loading}
                    onRefresh={this.refreshingHandler}
                />
            }
```

Expect request only be sent one time when doing Pull Refreshing in FlatList

=================

I found the way to revise it, like this, i commented those three lines , then Pull Refreshing work properly as of now, but do not know what footer related code making impact on it , below is the code :

```js
render() {
        return(
           <FlatList
            ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
            keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
            data={this.state.data}
            renderItem={this.renderItem}
            //onEndReached={this.handleLoadMore}
            //onEndReachedThreshold={0.1}
            //ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooterHandler}
            onRefresh={this.refreshingHandler}
            refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
            refreshControl = {
                <RefreshControl
                    refreshing={this.state.loading}
                    onRefresh={this.refreshingHandler}
                />
            }

           />
```

Answer (score 0):

[more details of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QivYl.png)

the screen shows more details of the issue :

Answer (score 0):

You might face this type of problem because You define onRefresh two times, either use it in FlatList or in RefreshControl.

Here is the solution! FlatList also has a prop called refreshControl like ListView but I just didn't test it! Like that:

```
refreshControl={
    <RefreshControl
        colors={["#9Bd35A", "#689F38"]}
        refreshing={this.state.loading}
        onRefresh={this.refreshingHandler}
    />
}
```